# Check the sum of a property of list items against another property

Tags: c#, list, linq, sum

I have a list of items on an order, along with the order totals.  I'm trying to find a way to add up all of the quantities that have shipped and compare that against the total order quantity, to see if there are any "backordered".

I get a list of PartInfo back, which includes all of the shipments of this product for an order.

```cs
public class PartInfo
{
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TrackingId { get; set; }
        public int ShippedQty { get; set; }
        public int OrderTotal { get; set; }
}
```

If I use the following data:

```
List<PartInfo> PartList = new List<PartInfo>();
PartList.Add(new PartInfo() { OrderId = "1031",
                              Name = "Watch", 
                              TrackingId = "1Z204E380338943508", 
                              ShippedQty = 1, 
                              OrderTotal = 4});

PartList.Add(new PartInfo() { OrderId = "1031",  
                              Name = "Watch", 
                              TrackingId = "1Z51062E6893884735", 
                              ShippedQty = 2, 
                              OrderTotal = 4});
```

How can I use LINQ to compare the total ShippedQty to the OrderTotal?

Comment: Is there also something like an `Order` class, and do you get the data from a database? It's great that you supply runnable code, but the real query could have to be substantially different in real application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer could be something like this:

```
var backOrdered = partList.GroupBy(p => new { p.OrderId, p.OrderTotal })
.Select(g => new
{
    g.Key.OrderId,
    g.Key.OrderTotal,
    TotalShipped = g.Sum(pi => pi.ShippedQty)
})
.Where(x => x.TotalShipped  < x.OrderTotal);
```

Assuming that `OrderId` and `OrderTotal` are always linked, so you can group by them and always have one group per `OrderId`.

But as I said in a comment, if the data comes from a database there may be better ways to get the data, esp. when there is an `Order` with a collection navigation property containing `PartInfo`s.

Answer (score 0):

My reading is that the `ShippedQty` is for the single item (`Name`) for the order, so you want to group the items by the `OrderId` and count the quantity shipped. In that case, you can use group by LINQ:

```
var groupResults = PartList.GroupBy(
    // Group by OrderId
    x => x.OrderId,
    // Select collection of PartInfo based on the OrderId
    x => x,
    // For each group based on the OrderId, create a new anonymous type
    // and sum the total number of items shipped.
    (x,y) => new {
        OrderId = x,
        ShippedTotal = y.Sum(z => z.ShippedQty),
        OrderTotal = y.First().OrderTotal
    });
```

For the sample data, this gives a single result, an anonymous type with three int properties (from C# interactive console):

```
f__AnonymousType0#3<int, int, int>> { { OrderId = 1031, ShippedTotal = 3, OrderTotal = 4 } }
```

You can then filter out the results to see where the order quantity is less than the order total

```
groupResults.Where(x => x.ShippedTotal < x.OrderTotal) ...
```

Comment: The counts were off when I tried this out.  I went with Gert's answer above.